# NoClassDefFound while profiling SpringBoot application with VisualVM

Tags: java, spring, profiling, visualvm

I'm trying to profile my SpringBoot app. In order to do that, I packaged it into jar file, here is part of my pom.xml. I can run this with `java -jar App.jar` and I can use my REST endpoints. It works fine.

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```

But, I want to profile it with VisualVM. To do that, I need to run is as

```
java -Xverify:none -jar App.jar
```

because otherwise, I get `Redefinition failed with error 62`. Application is running, REST endpoints are still working, but I can see that log.

> main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache
>   Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production
>   environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files
>   (x86)...

But as I said, it works, but profiling isnt working. After starting profiling CPU on VisualVM I get this stacktrace

> ERROR 6944 --- [alina-utility-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : Exception processing
>   background thread
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/embedded/TomcatWebServerFactoryCustomizer$$Lambda$304
>           at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.embedded.TomcatWebServerFactoryCustomizer$$Lambda$304/254749889.lifecycleEvent(Unknown
>   Source)

Comment: This is related to https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8145964 
You could try to download latest version of VisualVM and hope it has workaround.

Comment: I had a similar problem, basically explode your FAT JAR and try again. I just wrote this article about it: https://medium.com/kayvan-kaseb/tips-and-tricks-for-profiling-your-spring-boot-app-using-visualvm-de627cae02d1